Unable to validate data factory with global parameters that is not under GIT control using azure-data-factory-utilities NPM package
We have three ADF environments: DEV, TEST, and PROD and have implemented the new CI/CD flow as outlined in the link below.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery-improvements#continuous-deployment-improvements
While the normal CI/CD flow works fine, we are testing a hotfix flow where we can deploy directly to production from our hotfix branch.  When trying to generate an ARM template using the ADF utilities NPM package, we get errors indicating global parameter references in the pipelines are not found under the factory (same for the test factory which is also not under GIT control). When executing the exact same code and validating against the DEV factory (which IS under GIT version control), the ARM templates generate perfectly
The global parameters that it believes are missing are present in all factories as well as in the local directory where the resources are being validated against after we pull down the hotfix branch from Azure Repos.
YAML Command to validate
> - task: Npm@1   inputs:
>     command: 'custom'
>     workingDir: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)' #replace with the package.json folder
>     customCommand: 'run build validate $(Build.Repository.LocalPath) /subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-8ae8-49d5-8274-xxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/cfed-ngis-test-adf'   displayName: 'Validate'

Sample error from the NPM ADF utilities

ERROR === CmdApiApp: Resource 'Send_Pipeline_Failure' has the
following validation error: Parameter NotificationsEnable was not
found under cfed-ngis-test-adf

Based on what I'm seeing, the NPM package for ADF only seems to work correctly when it targets an ADF instance that has GIT enabled.  If this is not true, I'm looking for any suggestions on how to resolve this.
